# How many 4 digit integers using digits 1-9 are there so that the sum of digits is even?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many 4 digit integers using digits 1-9 are there so that the sum of digits is even?

I divide it into cases.

- Case 1, all even: $4^4$
- Case 2, no even: $5^4$
- Case 3, two even, two odd. *How should this be done?*

Comment: Concerning your case 3:
There are $\binom{4}{2}$ options to choose two places for the two even digits. You can fill these two places in $4^2$ possible ways. And the other two places can be filled with the odd digits in $5^2$ possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For case 3:

- Pick which two of the four digits are even: $\binom42=6$
- Assign the digits: $5^2\cdot4^2$

There are $6\cdot5^2\cdot4^2$ integers in this case. The total number of integers is $4^4+5^4+6\cdot5^2\cdot4^2=3281$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose two (out of four) of the digits to be odd, which you can do in ${}^4 C_2$ ways. Once you've decided which digits are going to be odd and which are going to be even, you can just select the digits in order, for which you have $4^2 5^2$ choices.